# How to wait until iframe will be loaded with Cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-iframe

I have dynamically loading iframe in a application.

I'm catching a frame through this code:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframeLocator: string): void => {
cy.wait(10000)
cy.get(iframeLocator)
    .its('0.contentDocument').should('not.be.empty')
    .its('body').should('be.visible')
    .then(cy.wrap)
})
```

The problem is that - without explicit timeout `cy.wait(10000)` conditions `not.be.empty` and `be.visible` are passing fine, while there is no content of iframe on the page yet.

How to catch iframe without explicit wait ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [cypress-iframe](https://npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin for this. After installing you can use the `frameLoaded` method.

```js
// This will verify that the iframe is loaded to any page other than 'about:blank'
cy.frameLoaded()
 
// This will verify that the iframe is loaded to any url containing the given path part
cy.frameLoaded({ url: 'https://google.com' })
cy.frameLoaded({ url: '/join' })
cy.frameLoaded({ url: '?some=query' })
cy.frameLoaded({ url: '#/hash/path' })
 
// You can also give it a selector to check that a specific iframe has loaded
cy.frameLoaded('#my-frame')
cy.frameLoaded('#my-frame', { url: '/join' })
```

Comment: Decided to try this library. With such code: `cy.frameLoaded(iframeLocator);
    cy
        .iframe(iframeLocator)
        .find(element)
        .click()`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that can stop `<iframe>` code working, including `cypress-iframe`.

- [lazy-loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-loading)

  ```html
  <iframe src="https://example.com"
          loading="lazy"                  
          width="600"
          height="400"></iframe>
  ```

  > Standardized lazy-loading of iframes defers offscreen iframes from being loaded until the user scrolls near them. This saves data, speeds up the loading of other parts of the page, and reduces memory usage.

- default loading content message e.g "Page is loading", falsely passes the `.should('not.be.empty')` check

- `<body>` element is changed when proper page is available, negating `.its('body').should('be.visible')` check

These are the additional steps I use

```js
// when iframe has attribute loading="lazy" 
cy.get(iframeLocator).scrollIntoView()   // start loading

cy.get(iframeLocator)
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('not.be.empty')
  .its('body')
  .as('body')           // alias this command chain

cy.get('@body')         // repeats above chain when <body> detached from DOM (replaced)
  .should('be.visible')
  .should('not.be.empty')
  .then(cy.wrap)
  .find('div#some-content', {timeout:10000})
```

Comment: Thank you, tested with cy v 10.

Answer (score 1):

An iframe may have "iframe is loading" default, so `not.be.empty` or `be.visible` are false checks.

Try content check and make sure `<body>` query is retried

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframeLocator: string): void => {
cy.get(iframeLocator)
    .its('0.contentDocument').should('not.be.empty')
    .its('body h1').should('contain', 'IFrame title')    // retry body
    .then(cy.wrap)
})
```